# Merging two tangled convex hulls

Tags: convex-hull, grahams-scan

How to merge two tangled convex hulls (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALM4G.jpg)) to form a Convex Hull using Graham's Scan or anyother algorithm in linear time?

Comment: Such merge should result in another c-hull?

Comment: If you want a c-hull of the whole thing, run Graham's Scan over the union of the points.  What is the question?

Comment: You could Also assign points of one Hull to faces of other Hull and "continue" process of quick-hull.

Comment: Do you have the polygons or just the points? If you have the polygons it can be done in `O(N + M)`. Otherwise, it's `O((N + m) log (N + M))`, though you could also use an output sensitive algorithm to improve the latter somewhat. Also, in the case of having the polygons, it means you can merge `K` convex hulls with a total of `P` points into a single convex hull in `O(P log K)` via `K-way merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you use
[Andrew's modification](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) of the Graham scan algorithm.

After the points are sorted in xy-order, the upper and lower hulls are computed in **linear** time. Since you already have the two convex hulls , the xy-sorting of the convex hull points will also take **linear** time (e.g., reverse the lower hulls and merge-sort four sorted lists).

Since the rest of the algorithm will take linear time, the overall runtime is linear as you requested.

Here is a reference to [some short python code](https://gist.github.com/arthur-e/5cf52962341310f438e96c1f3c3398b8) implementing Andrew's modification to Graham's scan. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71725431/9702190).